# How to show current information of the logged in user in php

Tags: php

Need some help about getting the information of the current logged in user and show it in the other page. I've using the session but seems no display at all. See below codes. But when I tried to dig further, it shows me an error like 'NOTICE: UNDEFINED INDEX: GIVEN NAME'... So, I would like you to help me solve this common problem because I'm stuck on it right now. Any help is much more appreciated for my thesis project.

CODE:

```
      <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->
                <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="dashboard.php"><i class="icon-home icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="users.php"><i class="icon-user icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Users</a></li>
                <?php 
                include('dropdown.php');
                ?>
                <li><a href="books.php"><i class="icon-book icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Books</a></li>
                <li><a href="member.php"><i class="icon-group icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Member</a></li>
                <li><a href="archive.php"><i class="icon-list-alt icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Archive</a></li>
                <li><a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-search icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Advance Search</a></li>


                <!-- <li><a href="section.php"><i class="icon-group icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Sections</a></li> -->
                <li><a href="logout.php"><i class="icon-signout icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
                 <div class="pull-right">
                    <div class="admin">


                    <?php
                    include_once("dbcon.php");

                     if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
                        { 
                        session_start(); 
                    } 

                    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
                        echo  "Welcome" . $_SESSION['givenname'];   
                    } 

                    ?>


                    </div>
                 </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**This is my login.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
session_start();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
$num_row = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if( $num_row > 0 ) {
        header('location:dashboard.php');
$_SESSION['id']=$row['user_id'];
    }
    else{ ?>
<div class="alert alert-danger">Access Denied</div>     
<?php
}}
?>
```

And this is the code of users.php

```
<?php $user_query=mysql_query("select * from users")or die(mysql_error());
                                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($user_query)){
                                $id=$row['user_id']; ?>
                                 <tr class="del<?php echo $id ?>">
                                <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td> 
                                <td><?php echo $row['password']; ?></td> 
                                <td><?php echo $row['givenname']; ?></td> 
                                <td><?php echo $row['surname']; ?></td> 
                                <td width="100">
                                    <a rel="tooltip"  title="Delete" id="<?php echo $id; ?>"  href="#delete_user<?php echo $id; ?>" data-toggle="modal"  class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-trash icon-large"></i></a>
                                    <?php include('delete_user_modal.php'); ?>
                                    <a rel="tooltip"  title="Edit" id="e<?php echo $id; ?>" href="#edit<?php echo $id; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-pencil icon-large"></i></a>
                                    <?php include('modal_edit_user.php'); ?>
                                </td>
                                <?php include('toolttip_edit_delete.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Shows us the code that is supposed to set the `$_SESSION['givenname']`

Comment: This is my login codes: <?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
 session_start();
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
 $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
 $num_row = mysql_num_rows($result);
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
  if( $num_row > 0 ) {
   header('location:dashboard.php');
 $_SESSION['id']=$row['user_id'];
  }
  else{ ?>
 <div class="alert alert-danger">Access Denied</div>  
 <?php
 }}
 ?>

Comment: 3 different session arrays. `$_SESSION['user_id'] $_SESSION['givenname'] $_SESSION['id']` don't ask yourself why it's failing. Plus, how do we know if your POSTs aren't failing also?

Comment: 3 different session arrays. $_SESSION['user_id'] $_SESSION['givenname'] $_SESSION['id'] don't ask yourself why it's failing. Plus, how do we know if your POSTs aren't failing also? – I already edit it from id to user_id and it works fine in my system but the only problem is it does not show in the heading. All are functioning very well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are storing name of the current logged in user on the `givenname` key of the `$_SESSION` variable.

Form your code I can understand that you are checking if `user_id` is set and then trying to print the value of `givenname`. But have you stored any value for `givenname` key?

Do this way:

`if ( isset($_SESSION['givenname']) ) {
     echo  "Welcome" . $_SESSION['givenname'];

 }`

Comment: Are you sure you are setting value to `$_SESSION['givenname']`? I would like to see the code where you are setting the value to `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 0):

Start session at the **very beginning of your page**. Before starting `<html>` tag and any outputs even any **white space**.

**UPDATE:**

In your login code change:

```
header('location:dashboard.php');
$_SESSION['id']=$row['user_id'];
```

to

```
$_SESSION['user_id']=$row['user_id'];
$_SESSION['givenname']=$row['username'];
header('location:dashboard.php');
```

Comment: You need to set up session in every page. Do you did that?

Comment: Already included session.php in every page along with database connection which is dbconn.php

Comment: try print_r($_SESSION); and check the output.

Comment: still no luck using this one: print_r ("Welcome" . $_SESSION['username']);

Comment: I don't tell you to do **print_r ("Welcome" . $_SESSION['username'])** but **print_r($_SESSION)**. print_r function print all element of an array. so this will outputs all the session variables.

Comment: What to do next, frankly I'm stuck on this? Ive change the code as written in your update.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you -> http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-PHP-Sessions.html
This will give all about session for better understanding.